# Automated feature generation for time series problems - Featuretools

Tags: python, featuretools

I'm trying to use featuretools to generate features to help me predict the number of museum visits next month.

Can featuretools generate features for time series? Should I changed the data so that the id is the month or can featuretools do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Featuretools can certainly help with this. Can you provide more information on the dataset and specific prediction problem so we can help?

Comment: I have a dataset that contain date of ticket purchase, date of museum visit, gender, age group, payment type, amount of payment. I want to predict the potential number of museum visits for next month.

Comment: is this a publicly available dataset?

Comment: No, the dataset is private

Comment: can you please direct me to the documentation that relates to formulating timeseries feature matrix.